# Configuring dhcp for multiple subnets

Tags: linux, dhcp, kickstart

I'm fairly new to configuring dhcp.  This would be for a kickstart server.  My question is, can I configure the dhcpd.conf file to be able to take in servers to be kicked over two different subnets?  Example:

server 1 to be kicked is in 7.100.10.0 subnet.
server 2 to be kicked is in 7.200.30.0 subnet.

Can this be configured over 1 NIC?  Or must I have a NIC for both subnets?

Comment: (1) You should use one DHCP server per broadcast domain, because DHCP is broadcast based. Two DHCP servers on the same broadcast domain are trouble. (2) If you mix different subnets on a single NIC, you'd better know what you are doing, because you'll run into issues that you need to know how to solve. A clean networking design wouldn't have two subnets on a single NIC, or use VNETs, or ... (but I'd need to see your network design for that).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be done, I've got 3 subnets being served. You just configure additional subnet pools. However, if they are all on the same lan, then you are going to have trouble, but can be overcome using classes.